# How to hide and show a separate div with CSS

Tags: css, html, properties, visibility

I have searched high and low trying to find the answer to this in respects to what I want to achieve here and found nothing. Maybe someone can help me out or point me in the right direction.

What I want to do is have an image gallery with thumbnails that when you mouse over display a larger image on the page that is normally hidden and dim the rest of the page.

I have seen a few tutorials out there explaining something similar but none of them showed exactly how to control one div's visibility by hovering another object.

Maybe I am just missing something simple here and if anyone can help me to understand how you can go about controlling the visibility property of div_a by hovering div_b

thanks
Evan

Comment: You will need to use something like jQuery to achieve the effect.  There should be a number of jquery plugins out there that will do the job you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing the opacity property of div_a when you change the z-index of div_b? Otherwise, if you're not opposed to using a bit of Javascript, you could use [Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). It is a lightweight script that does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: yeah i think i might have to resort to using lightbox. i was hoping to find someway of doing in with only css but from the looks of it i cant change properties in a neighboring div without using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Lowkase is spot on. You'll need javascript in some form, probably jQuery. Pick one of the many picture gallery packages out there and study the source code. Here's one to get you started: https://github.com/cube3x/Adipoli

Comment: thanks i think i will use lightbox to achieve the goal i am looking for. But the adipoli looks neat i am going to study the code and see if i cant impliment something similar on my own.